# Can IPtables (possibly with libnetfilter_queue library) do everything that snort does?

Tags: iptables, firewall, snort

I have just started getting into network security, firewall, etc. So, please excuse me for asking this basic question.

I looked at IPtables and got a good hang of it (nowhere close to becoming an expert) but understand the packet flow, hooks and to some extent the libnetfilter_queue library now. Just started looking at snort and thought that I could do most of snort with IpTables (worst case with some libnetfilter_queue C add-ons).

Is my observation correct?

Comment: I think you've already figured out by now, would you mind to share your findings with us?

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` can filter out approximately 60-70% of the `snort` rules if you use [fwsnort](http://www.cipherdyne.org/fwsnort/).